# Increasing voltage noise but decreasing current noise with rising resistance

Tags: noise, theory

Consider the two (equivalent) formulas for the noise power spectra of a ohmic resistor:

$$W_u(f)=4kT\cdot R~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(1)$$

and

$$W_i(f)=4kT\cdot G~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(2)$$

with the Boltzmann constant \$k\$, the temperature \$T\$, the resistance \$R\$ and the conductance \$G\$  each representing a equivalent circuit source.

General saying is that the noise increases with increasing value of resistance. E.g. in the datasheet for the AD745 it says that the noise contribution decreases with increasing resistance, which holds true for current noise considering formula (2), but is a contradiction considering formula (1).

Now, current noise produces a voltage noise when applied to a resistor with ohms law, but decreasing current noise and increasing resistance still yields a different result than just increasing voltage noise.

The equivalence of the circuits can be shown easily:

$$W_u(f)=W_i(f)\cdot\frac{1}{|G|^2}=\frac{4kT\cdot G}{G^2}=\frac{4kT}{G}=4kT\cdot R. ~~~~~~(3)$$

Please clarify the result in terms of noise of increasing the value of an ohmic resistor and explain the formulas (1) and (2) in the context of the stated contradiction?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple of talks the following might answer the question:

As stated above it holds that

$$W_i(f)=4kT\cdot G=\frac{4kT}{R}~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(2)$$

with the Boltzmann constant \$k\$ and temperature \$T\$. Increasing \$R\$ does indeed lower the current noise by \$1/R\$. You cannot measure current noise. It needs to be converted to voltage somehow, e.g. by a capacity or an i-v follower. So doing that eq. (3) from above gives the formula to convert the noise. The - measureable - voltage noise does indeed increase by \$R\$.

In conclusion: It cannot be stated that noise in general rises or decreases. One needs to differentiate b/w current and voltage noise. When it comes to practical and measureable considerations the Thèvenin source of eq. (1) should be used. Then, the noise rises proportional to \$R\$.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're comparing two different physical situations. (1) is for voltage across an open-circuit resistor, (2) is for current through a shorted resistor.

Comment: This is stated in theory, I agree. The two formulas still describe the Johnson-Nyquist noise of one and the same resistor at temperature \$T\$. For practical considerations the resistor (thought of as a source and a noise free resistor) will always have some kind of load, most of the time not impedance matched, lets say arbitrary. Still, one equivalent circuit would yield different results opposed to the other, no?

Comment: Thevenin equivalents- a noise voltage source with a noiseless resistor in series or a noise current source with a noiseless resistor in parallel.

Comment: Equivalents that yield different results then. I would be happy about some more clarification.